# In Java, how to get an ordered Set from Redis hkeys(key)?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I saved hash values in redis(jedis) just like below:

- (key, field, value)
- sampleKey, 01234::Test, firstValue
- sampleKey, 01234::Real, secondValue
- sampleKey, 01235::Test, firstValue
- sampleKey, 01235::Real, secondValue

And get a set using "Set set = jedis.hkeys(sampleKey)" and then converted into Array by System.arraycopy.
I checked the Array and the data is stored just like "01235::Test, 01234::Real, 01235::Real, 01234::Test". It is not stored in order.

I need to get the data in order..
Can anyone give me a help here~! Thank you.

Comment: why don't you sort the array after you got the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a TreeSet instead of a generic Set.

You, more likely, can't directly cast it, but you can try:

```
TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
```

To order by field:

```
set.addAll(jedis.hkeys(sampleKey));
```

To order by value:

```
set.addAll(jedis.hvals(sampleKey));
```

In a TreeSet, values are stored ordered. For custom objects you have to implement Comparable, but for primitives you don't need to do anything.

**Note:** Remember that order is case sensitive for Strings, since you are using numbers there is no problem, but if you use words, it will put capitalized words before.

Comment: Oh, I tought it was from keys since he used _hkeys_ on his example. Edited! EDIT: I'm actually not sure about if he wants to order by field or by value, so I added both

Comment: Yes, it's a bit confusing. He uses "sampleKey" to get the results but wants to sort by "field". As far as I understood the question.

Comment: The thing is, with jedis you can store with the same "key", multiple fields, each one with a value; if I understand correctly. And I understood he wanted to order by "field", not value, (hkeys returns all the fields).

Comment: Correct, just looked that up. So he requests all fields of a hash and wants a sorted list of those ... so I was mistaken about the Jedis API. Sorry about that. +1 for you.

Comment: This code won't compile.  `hkeys` and `hvals` returns a `Set`, you can't just coerce it into being a `TreeSet`

Comment: True, @tddmonkey I forgot the "addAll".